# Why did Sic Mundus not use the machines?

Tags: dark

Major spoilers ahead.

The members of Sic Mundus arrive in 1888 with the machine. They run out of fuel and try to find a way home.

Later alt Martha arrives, giving them the needed fuel. But instead of using it with the machine and try to return to home (what at least was the intention of Adams followers at first), they try to build their own "Sphere" from it.

Even later Hannah arrives with another (operational and presumably still fueled) machine. It seems unlikely she took a "one way trip". So now Sic Mundus should have two operational machines, one still fueled. But it seems that at that point in time they managed to get their "Sphere" working anyway?

So my question is, if they had a machine and fuel, why didn't they use it and instead stay there for some other decades?

Comment: The machine they use to go back to 1888 "breaks".  The time machine supposedly only allows travel 33 years into the future or the past from the point of activation.  The jump from 2020 to 1888 is four fold more than should be possible, which may explain why the machine broke.  I sort of remember them mentioning the machine kind of taps into the residual energy from the 1986 incident, which wouldn't exist in 1888, not until they get the fuel and start their own orb in the early 1900s.  This is an imperfect theory (the residual energy).

Comment: @McFuu - I don't think the suitcase time machine they used to get to 1888 was broken, if you look at the plausible reconstruction of the machine's history [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRM2KjU_OjQ), at 5:30 they talk about stranger Jonas using the machine to take Magnus, Franziska and Bartosz away from the apocalypse, ending up in 1888, but then suggest that Claudia obtained the machine from Sic Mundus sometime after this. The machine's jump from 2020 to 1888 was weird but you could imagine a power surge caused it to make 4 hops in quick succession when it had only been set for one.

Comment: @Hypnosfil - it's possible at some point after going back to 1888 that Claudia repairs the time machine, because at some point it doesnt require a cell phone anymore.  Regardless I've changed my mind slightly, even though I already stated half of this truth.  With the fuel that Alt Martha brings, even if the suitcase tm actually worked, it wouldn't take them any further than 33 years, which would be 1918-1930 timeframes (I forget when Alt Martha appears.)  Orb time machines are "perfect" they can go to anytime supposedly.

Comment: Ok, but 33 years further in the future would have been better than staying when they are, I think. That also begs a different question : If I use the machine to travel 33 years in one direction, why can't I simply repeat this multiple times to reach any time (in 33 steps of course) I like?